# generic type to add missing properties in type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the `onMessage` function that gets events from SDK of the third party in my app

```
interface TypeA {
    a:string,
    b:undefined
}

interface TypeB{
   b: 'a'|'b',
   c: 'a'|'b'
}

type TypeC = TypeA | TypeB

const onMassege=( event: TypeC )=>{
   if (event.a === 'a'){
       /*
       TS-ERROR 
       Property 'a' does not exist on type 'TypeC'
        .Property 'a' does not exist on type 'TypeB
        */
  }
  if ( event.b === 'a'){// good
  }
}
```

in the above example access to properties `event.a` get error from type-script but `event.b` does did not get any error because  `b` properties define in all types of `TypeC` interface

**I need a generic type to add missing properties in all types and add `c: undefined` to my `TypeC` interface**

[TS-playGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECCyDeAUMicnAFwDOYUoA5gDTGkBG5AriACYQygRdCAX0KFQkWIhQZsAISKtyyAORxlAH2UtlTUgiWqNW5cNFgs0iwGFkAXjQW86h3NEIA9iGrJPAWTiUlBB0ELYAFMgQAG4Q4OQyEDYAlLYAfAokwDBh0bFgAHRwdra2hkkZpCQA9ABUzJVoAMoAtACiAErtAPLtyPWVAApQ7thQ5ipqyFzuEJTIIO5gkQAewN6eyObYKglWJg2k%20UMj0OOGUzNzC0sQq%20sgmxY7FrL9lTVVzCLMWTkx4PkWMVSmpylUqsg6O53IIvsRRCIgA)

Comment: This is simple with only two types in TypeC but if there are more it's a little trickier

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just use the discriminated union "normally"? As in, check the shared property `b`.